# Maximize the pygame window without making it fullscreen

Tags: python, pygame, window, maximize, maximize-window

Is there a way to maximize the pygame window when intializing the window with `set_mode` without making it completely fulsscreen. I tried to get the required `window_size` by printing `event.size`, when `VIDEORESIZE` is called, which is `(1920, 1017)`. But if I use this value for my `window_size` when setting mode I just get a window at the same size of a maximized window. If I press maximize in the top right corner it just switches between a thicker and a thinner border.
Obviously i want the thinner border, is that possible from the start?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the
`RESIZEABLE`
When using `set_mode` in pygame like

`DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1017), RESIZABLE)`

Comment: That's what exactly what I did and it had the outcome described in the question.

Comment: So ur problem is basically u want thinner border.

Comment: Which is achieved by maximizing the window. I know how to do this, but i just want the window to open like this already